# Serialize ChoiceType field value options on Symfony API

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, jmsserializerbundle

When rendering a Symfony form in Twig I get all `ChoiceType` field value options in my `<select>` dropdown (collection of `<option>` tags within `<select>` tag)

This way user knows what options are available and if list of available options changes user can immediately see it.

Is there a way (except implementing custom serializer for each form, or my own serialization bundle obviously) when using Symfony as an API server, to let the frontend know what are available options for the `ChoiceType` fields?

Comment: Yes?  It depends what you're doing, how you're retrieving data, whether you're passing that to another Symfony form, how you're making the call, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Are you talking about specific library that does it?

Comment: Not really. Honestly it's pretty unclear what you're looking for